# cvRetrieveFrame crahses

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to write a simple openCV code that create a capture and retrieves the first frame from it.

```
**CvCapture *m_pCapfile = cvCreateFileCapture(m_aviFileName.c_str());
if (m_pCapfile)
     m_frames = cvRound(cvGetCaptureProperty(m_pCapfile, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));
cvSetCaptureProperty(m_pCapfile, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 0);
int ret = cvGrabFrame( m_pCapfile);
IplImage *cap = cvRetrieveFrame( m_pCapfile);**
```

In m_frames is have 153, which is the correct number of frames as far as I know.
cvGrabFrame returns 1 to ret however **cvRetrieveFrame** crashes.

I tries using **cvCaptureFromFile** and **cvCaptureFromAVI** instead of **cvCreateFileCapture**
In both cases **cvRetrieveFrame** method crashes.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What version of OpenCV are you using? Opencv is known to have such problems.

Comment: I have downloaded 2.4.0 and I have the same problem on that one as well

Answer (score 1):

`**CvCapture *m_pCapfile = cvCreateFileCapture(m_aviFileName.c_str());` 
Shouldn't this be CvCapture?

Like the following

```
CvCapture *m_pCapfile = cvCreateFileCapture(m_aviFileName.c_str());
```

I think you need to change the code to what I have suggested. Plus if this is your complete code, make sure during the loop in which you are retrieving the frames, you are not calling cvReleaseCapture(). This method is only called at the end when you have caught all the frames or the specified number of frames you want.

Comment: There is a release in the end, I just didn't copy it.
The code is actually the same as yours, the asterisks were added cause I tried to format the text and making the code look bold.
You can see that in the end of the code there are two additional asterisks

Comment: Oh, that was a new one for me, the double quotes!

Comment: Despite everything, the last few steps that might be useful for you is to install the drivers of your cam, see if your camera is even supported by opencv, donot mix any x64,x86 builds and even if that does not work, try rebuilding the binaries of OpenCV.

Comment: I am using a prerecorded AVI file

Comment: The crash is in **icvRetrieveFrame_FFMPEG_p**
In: 

    virtual IplImage* retrieveFrame(int)

    {

        unsigned char* data = 0;

        int step=0, width=0, height=0, cn=0;


        if(!ffmpegCapture ||
         !icvRetrieveFrame_FFMPEG_p(ffmpegCapture,&data,&step,&width,&height,&cn))

           return 0;
        cvInitImageHeader(&frame, cvSize(width, height), 8, cn);

        cvSetData(&frame, data, step);

        return &frame;

    }

Comment: Then if that is the cause,  FFMPEG might be the issue as OpenCV uses FFMPEG. Try one more thing. download FFMPEG separately http://ffmpeg.org and see if you can load it that way. This might be lengthy for you. Which OS are you using by the way? Can you send me the sample video?